# DC chart heatmap columns text rotation doesn't work

Tags: d3.js, rotation, heatmap

I'm trying this code in JS to rotate cols labels:

```
heatMap.renderlet(function (chart) {
chart.selectAll("g.cols text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,10)")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(315)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");});
```

But the only result is that all labels translate and rotate together:
[Heatmap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjWFX.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank's in advance

Comment: From the answer I linked, do:
`chart.selectAll("g.cols text").attr("transform", function(d){ var t = d3.select(this); return "rotate(315," + t.attr('x') + "," + t.attr('y') + ")"}).style("text-anchor", "end");`

Comment: It works! Thanks!